# how to set string b to equal a when a has spaces in it c

Tags: c

I have a string called that can continue a value with spaces for it as an example

```
char *a="this is a test"
```

I want to declare another string

```
char *b=NULL;
```

so I can then assign the value of a to b such as

```
b=a;
```

however currently b will only hold any characters up to the first space (in this example b= "this").
How do I get it to hold the entire string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not really "declare" a string. With

```
char *a="this is a test";
```

you assigned a literal string to a character pointer. With:

```
char *b=NULL;
b=a;
```

you assigned what `a` points to `b`, so you still have only one string (literal). Note that string literals generally reside in read-only memory and cannot be modified. What you could do is:

```
char a[]="this is a test";
char b[80];
strcpy(b,a);
```

Now you have two strings and can manipulate each independently.

Comment: I cannot however manipulate the char *a; how can I then store what is at the pointer in b?

Comment: The `strcpy` copies the string in `char a[]` to `char b[80]`. You have to think about this in terms of storage: you need to have storage (memory) to copy to. Note that `char a[]` is actually `char a[15]` but the compiler has calculated that `a` needs 15 bytes of storage.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried to do but I run into same issue I tried: b=malloc(sizeof(a)), strcpy(b,a,sizeof(a))

Comment: Copy my _exact_ example and it works.

Comment: `b=malloc(sizeof(a))` will not work because you malloc only the size of a POINTER, not the size of the string. For that use `malloc(strlen(a)+1)`

Comment: I was using strlcpy by mistake thank you so much ! you saved me.

Comment: and actually malloc is working for me